# How to make a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, notepad++, netbeans6.7

How can i make a jar file from both the command line and Netbeans 6.7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the [JAR](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) command:

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

Using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_make_my_first_Maven_project):

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html):

```
 <jar destfile="${dist}/lib/app.jar" basedir="${build}/classes"/>
```

Comment: jar cf jar-file input-file(s)

in the  input-file we have to write the name of file right?
like for example
jar cf jar-file Convert.java
???

Comment: @Sundhas - you want to put `.class` files in your JAR, not source files.

Comment: @Sundhas - Here is a concrete example "jar cf my.jar My.class"

Comment: Right get it now :)
Thanks alot Danben and Taylor L.

Comment: I have one more question..
How to execute that jar file via notepad? and whats the manifest folder all about? what it does?

Comment: To execute a jar file: java -jar app.jar

You will also need to have a MANIFEST.MF file in the META-INF directory that define the Main-class like this:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 6):

```
jar cf jar-file input-files
```

http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/build.html

Answer (score 3):

Command line:

```
jar cf jarfile [ -C dir ] inputfiles
```

Make sure you are `jar`-ing from the root of the directory matching your package hierarchy, rather than just the directory with the class files.  The directory structure needs to match the hierarchy.

Also, if you want the `JAR` to be executable, you need to include a [MANIFEST.MF](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html) containing a `Main-class` entry specifying which class should be used as the entry point (this class must define a `public static void main(String[] args)`).

Netbeans:  here is a link to a [tutorial](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/~dquigley/cse219/index.php?it=netbeans&tt=jar&pf=y).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways (enough already answered here), but if you want a REALLY SIMPLE way, look at Maven.  It just works: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html