# How to make jar file?

Tags: java, jar

Folder with program:

```
C:\ProgramFolder
```

In folder there is a package with classes:

```
com\mysite\my_program
```

Main class name:

```
Program.class
```

... or fullname:

```
com.mysite.my_program.Program
```

In the root folder there is manifest file with content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.mysite.my_program.Program
```

And I'm making jar-file:

```
jar cmf MANIFEST.MF my_program.jar com\mysite\my_program\*.class
```

and trying to lunch it:

```
java -jar my_program.jar -a -b -c http://google.com/ google
```

this:

```
-a -b -c http://google.com/
```

are paramerts to my program. Tesult is the same without them.

And I'am getting error:

```
Couldn't find or load main class Цjar
```

In real program manifest file looks like this:

[image: manifest file]

So, I don't know why **Цjar**

Comment: Does it really say `class Цjar` ? Open the jar file, look at the Manifest, if it somehow got messed up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179113/how-to-make-a-jar-file)

Comment: @Thilo Yes!) Ц - is a russian letter

Comment: @RC. I've read it before asking.

Comment: Can you run it with `java -cp my_program.jar com.mysite.my_program.Program -a -b -c http://google.com/ google`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>In C:\ProgramFolder create a subdirectory called META-INF and move the MANIFEST.MF into that, recreate your jar file. and try again.</strike>

EDIT

actually the jar m will add that into the right location, but you are missing Class-Path:

Comment: You are missing Class-Path in your manifest.mf as well ... you need to add `Class-Path: .` in there

Comment: Strange, but this helped. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `e` ([entrypoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html#entrypoint)) that way you may create a jar without adding [manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) file.

```
jar -cfe my_program.jar com.mysite.my_program.Program.class
```

or

`jar -cfe my_program.jar com/mysite/my_program/`Program.class

and launch the program:

```
java -jar my_program.jar -a -b -c "http://google.com/ google"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard way to create packages in Java.

Using command like this :

```
javac -d . *.java
```

But if you will simply make Folders and then treat it as packages it will not work.

Try making proper packages.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans id generate jar file automatically. You have no need to extra work for jar file. You have to just copy the project in NetBeans and compile it.